How to view all github user activity within an org?
I would like to see all of a user's activity within a public org. Is there a way to do that ?
The user doesn't own the org, or the repo, but they are a contributor and commenter.
How can I see all of a user's comments, pull requests, and commits etc on a certain org ?
If it isn't possible, just seeing all their activity in a given public repo would be okay too.  Thanks !

You can use GitHub REST API. Here I am using GitHub CLI to invoke these APIs for simplicity:
Repo events API works well with a classic PAT token with "repo" permissions:
GH_TOKEN=ghp_xxxxxxxx
gh api /repos/:org/:repo/events | jq -r '.[] | select(.actor.login == ":github-user") | [.type, .created_at, .repo.name, .actor.login] | @csv'

Org events API needs a fine-grained PAT token scoped to "events" under Org Permissions
GH_TOKEN=github_pat_xxxxxxxx    
gh api /users/:github-user/events/orgs/:org | jq -r '.[] | select(.actor.login == ":github-user") | [.type, .created_at, .repo.name, .actor.login] | @csv'

